# How to remove underline i md-chips in layout=row

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How can I get rid of the underline in md-chips - the line under 131, 132 and T ?

Code

```
<div layout="row">
  <div flex>
    <md-chips ng-model="condition.list" readonly="true" md-removable="false">
      <md-chip-template>
        <span>{{$chip.id}}</span>
      </md-chip-template>                  
    </md-chips>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Underline because `<md-chips>` adding border bottom.
You can remove that line by setting as below

```
.md-chips{
  box-shadow: 0 0px !important;
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {});
```

```css
.md-chips{
  box-shadow: 0 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div layout="row" ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div flex>
    <md-chips>
      <md-chip-template>
        <span>{{chip.id}}</span>
      </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you scope it like this: `md-chips .md-chips { ... }` then it will override material's style, and you won't need `!important`. Furthermore, `box-shadow: none;` is probably more straightforward...